# Tabindex not working after focus on childcomponent

Tags: html, angular, typescript, tabindex

I've made a typeahead that uses hostlistner to listen after focus and then activate focus on the input:

```html
<input #inputField type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt" [inputFormatter]="formatter" (selectItem)="emitResult($event)"/>
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
  {{r[displayKey]}}
</ng-template>
```

I listen after focus and set focus in the following way:

```js
@ViewChild('inputField') inputField: ElementRef;
  @HostListener('focus') focusIn() {
    if (!this.focused) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.focused = true;
        this.inputField.nativeElement.focus();
      });
    }
  }
```

And the problem Im having is that it messes up the tabindex in the parent view.

```html
<div class="col-12">
        <label for="sw">SW</label>
        <shrd-typeahead id="sw" autoFocus [data]="swList" [filterKey]="'name'" [displayKey]="'name'" (result)=selectedSw($event)
          tabindex="1"></shrd-typeahead>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12">
        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" [(ngModel)]="amount" tabindex="2">
      </div>
```

So I can set the focus without problem. But when I press "tab" after I've picked SW in the list I go to navigation in chrome instead of going to the next inputfield. :S
Is there a neat solution for this problem?

br

Comment: Do you properly "forward" the tabindex property from your custom shrd-typeahead component to the the actual input field? What is the behaviour when manually focusing the typeahead input? Maybe you can also create a stackblitz/plnkr showcasing the problem

Comment: How can one "forward" tabindex?

Comment: The typeahead component creates additional DOM elements (you may inspect them via the developer tools), attach the tabindex to the actual input field.

Comment: Thanks. 
Added tabindex as input to typeahead and then "tabIndex={{tabIndex}}" on the input in its html. So now it works!